# Can I use constants in a CASE?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a menu in typoscript who rely on id.
The proble is that the ids are hardcoded and I want to use constants instead. Is it possible ?

Here is the code who work well.

```
lib.navbar {
  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    special = directory
    special.value = {$lib.navbar.main}
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 1
        NO = 1

        NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject = CASE
        NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject {
            key.field = uid
            7062 = TEXT
            7062.value = <li class="first_level nav_home">|</li>
            7121 = TEXT
            7121.value = <li id="expositions" class="first_level">|</li>
            7142 = TEXT
            7142.value = <li class="nav_musee first_level">|</li>
            default = TEXT
            default.value = <li class="first_level">|</li>
        }
...
```

but can I use constants like that ?

```
lib.navbar {
  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    special = directory
    special.value = {$lib.navbar.main}
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 1
        NO = 1

        NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject = CASE
        NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject {
            key.field = uid
            {$constant1} = TEXT
            {$constant1}.value = <li class="first_level nav_home">|</li>
            {$constant2} = TEXT
            {$constant2}.value = <li id="expositions" class="first_level">|</li>
            {$constant3} = TEXT
            {$constant3}.value = <li class="nav_musee first_level">|</li>
            default = TEXT
            default.value = <li class="first_level">|</li>
        }
...
```

Comment: Have you tried it? what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

It was a different setup that was causing the problem.

I've just defined this constants in `constants.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt you could try is to use overrides instead of a case object.

Like this:

```
lib.navbar {
  10 = HMENU
  10 {
    special = directory
    special.value = {$lib.navbar.main}
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      noBlur = 1
      expAll = 1

      NO = 1
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject = TEXT
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject.value = <li class="first_level">|</li>
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject.value.override = <li class="first_level nav_home">|</li>
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject.value.override.if {
        insertData = 1
        value= {$constant1}
        equals.field = uid
      }
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject.value.override.override = <li id="expositions" class="first_level">|</li>
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject.value.override.override.if {
        insertData = 1
        value= {$constant2}
        equals.field = uid
      }
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject.value.override.override.override = <li class="nav_musee first_level">|</li>
      NO.wrapItemAndSub.cObject.value.override.override.override.if {
        insertData = 1
        value= {$constant3}
        equals.field = uid
      }
```

I did not test it, but could work.